# Has this vector occured before

Tags: c++, vector, stl, implementation

I have a lot of vectors (in the order of 10^4, even more!) And I will be getting more vectors in input from the stream. So, for example, I have

- `v1 = 1 0 4 1 1`
- `v2 = 1 1 2 5 3 6 2`
- `v3 = 0 1 1 5 0`

I have 10^4 such vectors 
Now, I get in input a vector `v4 = 0 1 1 5 0`,   And I want to check if it has appeared before or not, how do you suggest me to do this?

I will list the techniques I have thought of, and the errors which accompany them:

- To use `std::map`, or `std::set` for the same. But, `std::map  std::set` do not support vector as an argument.
- To convert every integer in vector to string type, append them in order and store the string in map.  Error: The case of  `v5 = 11 1 1 1`   and `v6 = 1 1 1 1 1` will be shown as same.
- Similiar to above, just to add a delimiter after every integer. Error: Too tedious to code?

I wished to know if you can think of some method to achieve this?

Edit:
for 10^4, it's achievable. My new task requires me to store upto 10^9. I personally don't think STL have that much space, they have thrown [SIGABRT](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7591/why-do-i-get-a-sigabrt/7592) error. Do you know any other efficient hashing method which can work in this case?

Comment: Converting a vector to a comma-separated string should not be very tedious. It seems like the simplest way to solve this.

Comment: I think a hash function would help

Comment: Did you consider a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)?

Comment: store the vectors in trie structure. Then you can check it very easily and effeciently

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc A hash function like? We have it that the maximum value of every element in the array <= 50. Probably I can multiply every element by index*50 and add, to get a key. Yes, it should. Will try it.

Comment: @TanujYadav Tries use more memory than I can afford.

Comment: @hiteshn97 what makes you think `std::set<std::vector<int>>` is not a valid type?

Comment: @Caleth When I tried it, it threw errors stating vector<int> is not a valid type, it would declare but at the insert function, it was throwing error. I tried again today with a different implementation, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple method of doing this is store your vectors in another vector, and maintain an order of that with the std::sort() family of functions, using std::lexigraphical_compare as the sort predicate. This would allow for binary searching the list in O(log(n)) amortized time, at the expensive of a semi-costly sort operation, which can probably be reduced by playing some games with heapifying or partitioning your list-of-vectors as you load it.

More efficient than this, however, is to store your vectors as a trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), where each path down the trie stores a unique sequence from your vectors. Depending on the variance in your data, this can be much more space-efficient, and both addition and search are O(log(n)) operations.

Take my advice with a grain of salt, however, 10^4 elements is actually a tiny number. My experience is that differences in the efficiency sorting & searching algorithms really only start to show themselves on modern hardware when you're in the 10^6-10^7 range for your data set. Below that scale, oft times the simplest, most cache-friendly algorithm wins out.

Another alternative if you're just going for raw speed, and your list of vectors to scan for is well known and static, is to use a finite state machine to accept/reject your input. Tools like Ragel can make short work of such problems.

Comment: The first method. I didn't get it. What I could make out is you;re sorting the vector, but then will your algorithm be able to differentiate between {1,2,3} and {3,2,1} ?

Answer (score 1):

This is very begineer approach but I am trying to use what I have learned from folding and stl

Explanation of the approach:

1.Created a list of vector (for input purpose can be anyway around)

2.Kept a main vector v which will store the main folded vector

3.used stl includes to keep checking before folding if the sequence is present

Set of inputs

```
std::vector<int> x ={1,2,3};
std::vector<int> y ={7,8,9};
std::vector<int> z ={1,2,3};
std::vector<int> a ={1,2,3};  
std::vector<int> v5 = {11,1,1,1}; //as mentioned in question
std::vector<int> v6 = {1,1,1,1};  //as mentioned in question
```

Approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
void Concat(std::vector<T>& v, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
    v.insert(v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
}

template <typename T>
void Concat(std::vector<T>& v, const T& value)
{
    v.push_back(value);
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void push_back_vec(std::vector<T>& v, Args&&... args)
{
    (Concat(v, args), ...);
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::list<std::vector<int> > m ;
    std::vector<int> x ={1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> y ={7,8,9};
    std::vector<int> z ={1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> a ={1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> v5 = {11,1,1,1};
    std::vector<int> v6 = {1,1,1,1};
    m.push_back(x);
    m.push_back(y);
    m.push_back(z);
    m.push_back(a);
    m.push_back(v5);
    m.push_back(v6);

    for (std::list<std::vector<int> >::iterator it1 = m.begin(); it1 != m.end(); ++it1)
    {


        if (std::includes(v.begin(), v.end(), (*it1).begin(), (*it1).end()))
        {
            std::cout<<"Already present"<<std::endl;
            }
        else
            {
            push_back_vec(v,(*it1));

            }
    }

    for (int i : v) std::cout << i << ' ';

}
```

Output

```
Already present
Already present
1 2 3 7 8 9 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I know there can be lot of improvement and it may fail in some corner case .This is just one of the attempt Feel free to criticize and help me to improve

Comment: I don't know much about folding of vectors. I tried googling it, but didn't find any useful resource. Can you provide me with a link?
And what would be the time complexity of your algorithm. O(n) will be too large!

Answer (score 1):

If you define a complete ordering on your vectors, you can do a reasonably efficient lookup two ways:

- store the existing vectors in a `std::set` or `std::map`.  These are ordered container classes, with reasonably efficient membership/lookup methods.
- store the existing vectors in sorted order in a `std::vector`, and use `std::binary_search`

The default choice for ordering your vectors is lexicographic order.  This is provided by the `operator<` provided by the `std::vector` implementation; what it actually does is something like this:

```
bool operator<(const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b) {
  auto a_it = a.cbegin();
  auto b_it = b.cbegin();
  while(a_it < a.cend() && b_it < b.cend()) {
    if(*a_it < *b_it) {
      return true;
    }
    if(*b_it < *a_it) {
      return false;
    }
    ++a_it;
    ++b_it;
  }
  if(a_it == a.cend() && b_it < b.cend()) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that this code can exit early:  if the first elements of the input vectors are different, it doesn't need to check any further.  Only if there is a long common prefix (or if the vectors are actually identical) does it need to check all the elements.

---

As mentioned in the comments, you can also solve this problem with:

- a hash map (`std::unordered_map`) -- requires you define a hash for your `std::vector<int>`
- a trie -- which AFAIK doesn't have a `std::` implementation, you need to track down a library or roll your own

Comment: There [already exists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) `namespace std { template< class T, class Alloc > bool operator<( const vector<T,Alloc>& lhs, const vector<T,Alloc>& rhs ); }` I.e. the default of `std::less<std::vector<int>>` works fine

Comment: I noticed you use a.cbegin() instead of a.begin() , is there a specific reason? or just a personal choice? Probably to ensure you don't change the content of the vector? Probably because you passed by reference. Is it right?
Why did you return true in this condition? `if(*a_it < *b_it)  return true;`

Comment: Think alphabetical order:  to determine if `"cat" < "dog"`, you first check if `'c' < 'd'`.  If so, you know that `"cat"` comes first -- you don't need to check any other characters, you know the result is `true`.

Comment: Also, I used `cbegin()` to emphasize that the input is constant.